# Java: Binary Search Implementation not working using Deferred detection of equality

Tags: java, search, binary

I am trying to implement Binary Search Java version. From wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Deferred_detection_of_equality I noticed that deferred detection of equality version. It's working using that algorithm. However, when I was trying to change the if condition expression like this:

```
    public int bsearch1(int[] numbers, int key, int start){
    int L = start, R = numbers.length - 1;
    while(L < R){
        //find the mid point value
        int mid = (L + R) / 2;
        if (numbers[mid] >key){
            //move to left
            R = mid - 1;
        } else{
            // move to right, here numbers[mid] <= key
            L = mid;
        }
    }
    return (L == R && numbers[L] == key) ? L : -1;
}
```

It's not working properly, which goes into an infinity loop. Do you guys have any ideas about it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Define "not working properly". Are you getting an error? Is it not giving the right output?

Comment: @ObliviousSage it goes into the infinity loop and never return the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed the effect of the `assert` in the Wiki you link to.

It states:

> code must guarantee the interval is reduced at each iteration

You must exit if your `mid` >= `R`.

**Added**

The Wiki is actually a little misleading as it suggests that merely ensuring `mid < r` is sufficient - it is not. You must also guard against `mid == min` (say you have a `4` entry array and `l = 2` and `r = 3`, `mid` would become `2` and stick there because `2 + 3 = 5` and `5 / 2 = 2` in integer maths).

The solution is to round **up** after the `/ 2` which can be easily achieved by:

```
  int mid = (l + r + 1) / 2;
```

The final corrected and tidied code goes a little like this:

```
public int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int key, int start) {
    int l = start, r = numbers.length - 1;
    while (l < r) {
        //find the mid point value
        int mid = (l + r + 1) / 2;
        if (numbers[mid] > key) {
            //move to left
            r = mid - 1;
        } else {
            // move to right, here numbers[mid] <= key
            l = mid;
        }
    }
    return (l == r && numbers[l] == key) ? l : -1;
}

public void test() {
    int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 5, 6};
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        System.out.println("Searching for " + i);
        System.out.println("Found at " + binarySearch(numbers, i, 0));
    }
}
```

There is a trivially similar algorithm [here](http://wiki.beyondunreal.com/User:Wormbo/Random_useful_code_snippets) that suggests the correct approach looks more like:

```
public int binarySearch(int[] numbers, int key) {
    int low = 0, high = numbers.length;
    while (low < high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (numbers[mid] < key) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            high = mid;
        }
    }
    return low < numbers.length && numbers[low] == key ? low : -1;
}
```

This takes a slightly different approach to the boundary conditions where `high = max + 1` and also works perfectly.

Comment: that's awesome!!! The method introduced in Wiki page uses Round down: imid = (int)floor((imin+imax)/2.0); Thank you for pointing out it.

Comment: @Patrick - The wiki mentions several techniques for finding the median, none of them address the issue you found. I think you found a bug in Wikipedia. :)